# Jquery Slider display scale on slider bar

Tags: jquery, slider, scale

I have used [jquery slider](http://jqueryui.com/demos/slider/#rangemin) with the help of which user select appropriate value for further calculation.

Everything work perfect except the scale bar. I want to show the diffrent values of the slider to be displayed on slider bar. Something like slider scale. I have google it but I could not get the proper solution.

Can any one tell me how to achive this?

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean... can you go into further detail?

Comment: I Want slider to show the slider values on slider bar some thing like scale.

Comment: Hi all,
I have not get the solution for this issue :( so finally what I did is, with the help designer I have created Scale Image along with marking of measure on the top side of image. I have set this Image as background Image for my slider. Now when my slider moves to value lets say $1000 it get positioned exactly underneath of measure value $1000 on the Image. As slider values require for me was specific and not going to changes further so this Image was solved my problem.

But again this was my workaround for this issue and not a solution...!

Answer (score 5):

I don't think jquery-ui slider has provision to show labels like scale across the slider length. So a very good alternative to it is using an another plugin which has support for such a customization.

Take a look at this plugin : http://simeydotme.github.io/jQuery-ui-Slider-Pips/